# How to send JSON request parameters while submitting the form? (instead of $.ajax request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to send JSON request parameters to server while submitting the form?

```
function fun2() {
alert("in fun2");
document.searchForm.action = "http://localhost:8080/DatasetRepo/rest/downloadZip?"+"{'datasets':['1'],'token':'myfirsttoken'}";
document.forms["searchForm"].submit();}
```

and its failing with Unsupported media type error.

Comment: check this questions answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446544/post-request-to-include-content-type-and-json 
browsers don't support json as media type for POST.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

or

```
$.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Comment: The OP would need jQuery to do this... it is not a valid answer to the question. Also specified to not use $.ajax... $.post and $.get are shorthand $.ajax requests

Comment: Yes. zgr024 is absolutely right... Needed form submission and get the download from server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize` to get form data, like

```
var form=$('form[name=searchForm]');
$.post(url, form.serialize(),callback)
```

Comment: Not looking for $.post or ajax related stuff. Have to send json and get the download from server...(if I send thru ajax, getting download is becoming difficult)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending as json, just send as querystring...

```
function fun2() {
    document.searchForm.action = "http://localhost:8080/DatasetRepo/rest/downloadZip?datasets[]=1&token=myfirsttoken";
    document.forms["searchForm"].submit();
}
```

Then the document you are posting to will have the values in the $_GET array...

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Comment: Its failing with Unsupported Media type as server code in java expecting json. I have jsonMessageConverter in spring configuration.

Comment: You won't be able to do this directly from a form submission. In PHP, i use curl. In Java it's very similar. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java for info

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a good approach to take, as if you want to send JSON, you will also want to set Contetn-Type header to `application/json` so the receiving server understands that it is not dealing with a URL-encoded query string as you would be with typical form posts.  Most browsers do not yet support using form `enctype="application/json"` as this is still just a draft part of HTTP spec.

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing this info. Even I tried that putting enctype="application/json" in form tag. but did not work. Do you have any suggestion for doing this? (Because I have to get a download from server, ajax requests I can't go with)

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify function to send json in ajax post, below snippet can be used to send data using ajax.

```
var data = {
      one: 'first',
      two: 'second'
};

function formSubmit(url, data) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    ajaxCallback(xmlhttp);
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
 }

 function ajaxCallback(xmlhttp) {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      console.log(response);
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: May be I can change Content-type to applicaiton/json as server is expecting json format. But can you suggest me to take a download from server as application/octet-stream by using this xmlhttp object or somehow?

Comment: Yes, Change content-type to application/json or convert json to query string to send data. I don't think you can download any file using xmlhttp object instead you can get a whole stream of a file as a string in json that could be processed later.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post the data to a PHP script and use curl to send the content type and post data.

If you are using Java, it's similar. See [How to use cURL in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java)

In either case, you can't send json content type directly from a form yet and will need to use server side scripting to accomplish your goal.

Hope that helps.