# How to change the form to Content-Type: application / json

Tags: javascript, express

Hello I have a simple form and I want to send it with post and get it later with express library, my problem when I submit shipping status is application / x-www-form-urlencoded and I want Content-Type: application / json.
How do I change it?
To understand me, I added my code.

```html
<form action="http://localhost:3000/test" method="POST" class="card" >
      <div><label for="nameinvstement">:שם השקעה</label></div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="nameInvstement" id="nameinvstement" required />
      </div>
      <button type="submit"></button>
      <form/>
```

```js
app.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
  const {
    nameInvstement,
  
  } = req.body;
  try {
    await collection.insertOne({
      nameInvstement,
      
    });
    res.status(200).json("OK");
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post request to include 'Content-Type' and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446544/post-request-to-include-content-type-and-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the `app.use` as you can specify outputs like below:

**Parses**: `application/json`

```
app.use(express.json())
```

**Parses**: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }}
```

**Example**:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/testing', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Start submitting");
    console.log(req.body);
}
```